# why virtual table matters?

Tags: c++, function, virtual, vtable

To implement dynamic binding, for each class, there is a virtual table to store addr of each function. Why this indirection is needed? can we just have the class directly store the ptr to the correct function?

Comment: Not for every class. For every object. And yes, we could, but that would be extremely wasteful and complicate the resulting machine code.

Comment: If each object had to store pointers to the proper functions, the memory overhead of polymorphic classes would be unreal

Answer (score 6):

You could in fact do that. And then *every instance* of *every polymorphic class* would need to have its entire virtual table stored as part of the object. For classes with a large number of virtual methods this would be a significant memory overhead. There's no guarantee it would even be faster because you could decrease cache locality by storing so much redundant data.

Comment: If you want to figure out how it works, imagine writing a compiler and figuring out just from the source code which actual functions to call and when. The bits where you don't know (because you only have a pointer to the base class, for example) are where the virtual table comes in.